# Ruby on Rails Instance Variable not being set via form's submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app starts out with a form that takes a string as your location, upon clicking submit it should pass this string into a gem-api call that will return an array of json that I then parse and display.  The problem I have is clicking submit leaves the instance variable as nil still.

Here is the form that you see on the 1st page:

```
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.text_field :address, :placeholder => "City State" %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Find Coffee!" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the controller's code:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /locations
  # GET /locations.json
  def index
    @location = Location.new
  end

  # POST /locations
  # POST /locations.json
  def create
    @shops = []
    @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new('###API KEY####')
    @shops = @client.spots_by_query('coffee near ' + @location.address)
  end

  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:address)
    end
end
```

So what happens when I fill in the form and click submit is I get an undefined method @location.address for nil, when I set it all up in rails console it works as I want so it's just a matter of getting the @location = Location.new and then passing the address in to it.  What am I missing?

Comment: Somehting to consider is that you can set class level variables using @@variable instead of @variable however this is rarely the correct solution.  Brians answer below is the correct way of doing things in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables you define in one action don't get defined in another action. They are completely different blocks of memory.

```
  def create
    @shops = []
    @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new('###API KEY####')
    @shops = @client.spots_by_query('coffee near ' + @location.address)
  end
```

Should be

```
  def create

    @shops = []
    @location = Location.create(location_params)
    @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new('###API KEY####')
    @shops = @client.spots_by_query('coffee near ' + @location.address)
  end
```